# Concatenate two tensors of different shape from two different input modalities

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, concatenation

I have two tensors:

```
a = torch.randn((1, 30, 1220)) # represents text embedding vector (30 spans, each with embedding size of 1220)
b = torch.randn((1, 128, 256)) # represents image features obtained from a pretrained CNN (object detection)
```

1. How do I concatenate everything in `b` to each one of the 30 spans of `a`?
2. How to concatenate the whole `b` to the whole `a`?

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image: Image features concatenated with LSTM output]

The authors have only provided this text:

[image: Model description]

I'm extracting features (outlined in red) from a 3d point cloud (similar to CNN but for 3d) as shown below:

[image: 3D Feature Extraction]

Comment: *[...] `128, 256)`*: are those your spatial dimensions?

Comment: Yes, those are spatial dimensions representing position of all the objects in the image.

Comment: Do they not describe the dimensions of `e_n` in more detail?

Comment: This is what I found for e_n (which is the vectorized span representation)
`Shape: (batch_size, num_spans, embedding_size + 2 * encoding_dim + feature_size)`

Comment: Ok, there seems to be a missing piece though, if you want to concatenate those on `axis=2`, you need to have `num_spans` somewhere in your CNN output. Do you know what `num_spans` corresponds to? Is it arbitrarily chosen?

Comment: So, for a text '**This is a man eating pizza**', the model considers all possible span of words. So, the spans are 'This', 'This is', 'This is a', and so on. `num_spans` here represents how many spans do we have for each input text. CNN wouldn't know anything about it as it's only dealing with the image, not the text.

Comment: @Ivan For image features, 128 represents the number of proposals for object detection generated by the network. So, maybe I could only keep the same number of proposals as the num_spans and then concatenate along axis=2? I would end up losing a lot of information about the other objects but it's better than having none

Comment: @Ivan what happens if I flatten the image feature vector and then concatenate with text vector along `axis=2`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236717/discussion-between-sam-and-ivan).

Comment: If you flatten your image features you end up with a shape of `(1, 32768)` which won't match the embedding's size...

Comment: Yes, so I was thinking I could unsqueeze a dimension  to `(1, 30, 32768)` and then concatenate with `(1, 30, 1220)`.

Comment: Where do you pull that `30` on `axis=1`?

Comment: I was thinking I could just repeat `32768` 30 times.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, that's too much redundancy.

Comment: Yes that's true but I'm fine with that as long as it doesn't mess with the data. Do you think flattening the image feature vector will make it 'lose meaning'?

Comment: Could you show your model definition? especially the CNN. That will help me get an idea.

Comment: I updated the question with details on model from which I'm extracting features. It's based on the first image but I'm doing it for 3d point cloud instead of images.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to combine two tensors with different shapes, there is no trivial way of *concatenating* them. Both tensors hold information regarding the same instance: the element you want to characterize with features embeddings through two different modalities: textual and visual.

The only way that makes sense to me is to learn two separate layers to map your text embedding and your image features to a common space where you can easily fuse them.

The design you adopt for this mapping is entirely up to you. Of course, this *mapping* layers need to be learned through training *i.e.* applying some kind of supervision at the other end.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated the question with more information on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The first tensor is for the textual description describing the objects in the image, whereas the second tensor is the learned features for each object in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Since these representations are from two different modalities (i.e., text and image) and they contain valuable features that are of great importance to the final goal, I would suggest to *fuse* them in a "learnable" manner instead of a mere concatenation or addition. Furthermore, such a learnable weighting (between features) would be optimal since in some cases one representation would be far more useful than the other whereas at other instances the vice versa applies.

Please note that a mere concatenation can also happen in this fusion module that you would implement. For the actual implementation, there are several types of fusion techniques. E.g. Simple Fusion, Cold Fusion etc. (cf. [Fusion Models for Improved Visual Captioning, 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.15251))

For instance, one straightforward idea would be to use a simple linear layer to project one of the features to the same dimensionality as the other and then do a simple concatenation, with some optional non-linearity if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenation as followד:

```py
concatenatedTensor = torch.cat([torch.reshape(firstTensor,[-1]),torch.reshape(secondTensor,[-1]))
```